# Trouble with disposing a control within function

Tags: vb.net, plugins

I am attempting to write a simple plugin for MusicBee (a music player app)
I am building on the example provided with the API.

Some background: this plugin is launched when the main .exe (musicbee) launches.
The  `Configure()` function is run when the user goes to the plugin config screen in the options menu.

The
    `Dim configPanel As Panel = DirectCast(Panel.FromHandle(panelHandle), Panel)
 Dim btn1 As New Button`
and `configPanel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {btn1})`
lines add a button to this config screen which I am using to enable/disable the only function of my plugin.

To provide user feedback I need to change the text of this button (i.e. "ON", "OFF")

The problem: If I declare the button inside the `Configure()` function I cannot access it from the other click event function. (`btn1_Click()`)

If I declare it globally then when the user closes the config screen (not the whole plugin) `btn1` gets disposed (actually `configPanel` gets disposed by the musicbee API I think). When the user tries to open the config screen again I get an exception because it tries to access `btn1` when it was already disposed and is not re-declared.

`MusicBee v3.0.6132.15853 (Win6.1), 7 Mar 2017 20:53:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Button'.`

There must be a way to declare/setup `btn1` so that this works but I don't know how.

Thanks, Timothy.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Plugin
    Private mbApiInterface As New MusicBeeApiInterface
    Private about As New PluginInfo
    Dim playMode As Boolean


    Public Function Initialise(ByVal apiInterfacePtr As IntPtr) As PluginInfo
        CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 4)
        If mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_0 Then
            ' MusicBee version 2.0 - Api methods > revision 25 are not available
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 456)
        ElseIf mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_1 Then
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 516)
        ElseIf mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_2 Then
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 584)
        ElseIf mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_3 Then
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 596)
        ElseIf mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_4 Then
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 604)
        ElseIf mbApiInterface.MusicBeeVersion = MusicBeeVersion.v2_5 Then
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, 648)
        Else
            CopyMemory(mbApiInterface, apiInterfacePtr, Marshal.SizeOf(mbApiInterface))
        End If
        about.PluginInfoVersion = PluginInfoVersion
        about.Name = "Single Play Mode"
        about.Description = "Adds a single play mode i.e play one track and stop."
        about.Author = "Timothy Hobbs"
        about.TargetApplication = ""  ' current only applies to artwork, lyrics or instant messenger name that appears in the provider drop down selector or target Instant Messenger
        about.Type = PluginType.General
        about.VersionMajor = 1  ' your plugin version
        about.VersionMinor = 0
        about.Revision = 1
        about.MinInterfaceVersion = MinInterfaceVersion
        about.MinApiRevision = MinApiRevision
        about.ReceiveNotifications = ReceiveNotificationFlags.PlayerEvents
        about.ConfigurationPanelHeight = 40  ' height in pixels that musicbee should reserve in a panel for config settings. When set, a handle to an empty panel will be passed to the Configure function
        Return about
    End Function


    Public Function Configure(ByVal panelHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
        ' save any persistent settings in a sub-folder of this path
        Dim dataPath As String = mbApiInterface.Setting_GetPersistentStoragePath()
        ' panelHandle will only be set if you set about.ConfigurationPanelHeight to a non-zero value
        ' keep in mind the panel width is scaled according to the font the user has selected
        ' if about.ConfigurationPanelHeight is set to 0, you can display your own popup window
        If panelHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            Dim configPanel As Panel = DirectCast(Panel.FromHandle(panelHandle), Panel)
            Dim btn1 As New Button

            btn1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
            btn1.Size = New Size(150, 25)
            btn1.Text = "Single Play Mode: OFF"

            playMode = False
            configPanel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {btn1})
            AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf btn1_Click
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'toggle play mode
        If playMode Then 'We are in single play mode so turn it OFF
            playMode = False
            btn1.Text = "Single Play Mode: OFF" '*******ERROR HERE*******
            If mbApiInterface.Player_GetStopAfterCurrentEnabled() Then
                mbApiInterface.Player_StopAfterCurrent() 'disable it
            End If
            'also disable stopaftercurrent once more for the current song.

        Else 'We are in normal play mode so turn it ON
            playMode = True
            btn1.Text = "Single Play Mode: ON"  '*******AND HERE*******
            'enable it once
            If Not mbApiInterface.Player_GetStopAfterCurrentEnabled() Then
                mbApiInterface.Player_StopAfterCurrent() 'enable it
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


    ' called by MusicBee when the user clicks Apply or Save in the MusicBee Preferences screen.
    ' its up to you to figure out whether anything has changed and needs updating
    Public Sub SaveSettings()
        ' save any persistent settings in a sub-folder of this path
        Dim dataPath As String = mbApiInterface.Setting_GetPersistentStoragePath()
    End Sub

    ' MusicBee is closing the plugin (plugin is being disabled by user or MusicBee is shutting down)
    Public Sub Close(ByVal reason As PluginCloseReason)
    End Sub

    ' uninstall this plugin - clean up any persisted files
    Public Sub Uninstall()
    End Sub

    ' receive event notifications from MusicBee
    ' you need to set about.ReceiveNotificationFlags = PlayerEvents to receive all notifications, and not just the startup event
    Public Sub ReceiveNotification(ByVal sourceFileUrl As String, ByVal type As NotificationType)
        ' perform some action depending on the notification type
        Select Case type
            Case NotificationType.PluginStartup
                ' perform startup initialisation
                Select Case mbApiInterface.Player_GetPlayState()
                    Case PlayState.Playing, PlayState.Paused
                        ' ...
                End Select
            Case NotificationType.TrackChanged
                If playMode Then 'if single play mode is enabled
                    If Not mbApiInterface.Player_GetStopAfterCurrentEnabled() Then
                        mbApiInterface.Player_StopAfterCurrent() 'enable it
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub

    ' return an array of lyric or artwork provider names this plugin supports
    ' the providers will be iterated through one by one and passed to the RetrieveLyrics/ RetrieveArtwork function in order set by the user in the MusicBee Tags(2) preferences screen until a match is found
    Public Function GetProviders() As String()
        Return New String() {}
    End Function

    ' return lyrics for the requested artist/title from the requested provider
    ' only required if PluginType = LyricsRetrieval
    ' return Nothing if no lyrics are found
    Public Function RetrieveLyrics(ByVal sourceFileUrl As String, ByVal artist As String, ByVal trackTitle As String, ByVal album As String, ByVal synchronisedPreferred As Boolean, ByVal provider As String) As String
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    ' return Base64 string representation of the artwork binary data from the requested provider
    ' only required if PluginType = ArtworkRetrieval
    ' return Nothing if no artwork is found
    Public Function RetrieveArtwork(ByVal sourceFileUrl As String, ByVal albumArtist As String, ByVal album As String, ByVal provider As String) As String
        'Return Convert.ToBase64String(artworkBinaryData)
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Maybe this is causing your issue `If panelHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then` second time round? Is `panelHandle <> IntPtr.Zero`?

Comment: Yes, the if statment is executed the second time because the exeption is thrown on the `configPanel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {btn1})` line. My issue is that if I decalre `btn1` as global then its not declared the second time when I try to add it to the panel.

Comment: OK are you sure it's the button then and not the panel itself? Check that `configPanel` isn't Null (Nothing). Also I think you should be able to just use the `.Add` method and add the button control instead of `.AddRange`. Additionally whenever you _have_ finished with the button you should use `RemoveHandler`.